# CSS Padding overflowing on hover of fixed height div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a site and I added previous and next buttons to my posts which I'm creating via a wordpress theme. For some reason on the hover stage of these blocked elements which are links the padding pushes beyond the max height and I can't figure out how to correct this problem. If you take a look at the link

http://hearthable.com/hearthstone-account-wipe/

At the end of the post content you will see Previous Post and Next Post. If you hover over either one you'll see the issue with the padding. I've been trying everything and haven't been able to figure out to not get the hover to flow over.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different solutions:

1. Use `box-sizing: border-box`:

   ```
   #browse-posts a {
       position: relative;
       display: block;
       padding: 20px 40px 0;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #888;
       height: 85px;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Some Webkit versions requires a prefix */
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Gecko (i.e. FireFox) requires a prefix */
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   ```

   [Compability tables are available here](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

   You can read more about CSS3 `box-sizing` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), [QuirksMode](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html) or other good places. Avoid     W3Schools like the plague.
2. Calculate the height as `height = desiredHeight - border - padding`.

   ```
   #browse-posts a {
       position: relative;
       display: block;
       padding: 20px 40px 0;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #888;
       height: 65px; // 85px - 20px padding
   }
   ```

---

Finally, you can drop the `height: 85px` from `#browse-posts a:hover`, it is inherited anyway.

Comment: Thank you, Why was the padding not pushing past the 85px height limit when I wasn't hovering? I think that was the reason that was really confusing me since during non hover it looked good, but the hover state was different even though they had the same padding.

Comment: Actually, it was, but since the background is transparent when *NOT* hovering, you didn't see it unless you use a dev tool, such as the developer bar in Chrome/Safari/Firefox

Answer (score 0):

if you have used padding, along with it you should do something else to make the element fits to its original height.

example

```
div{width: 100px;}
div:hover{padding-left: 5px;}
```

in this case on hover effect you have added padding left, which makes the div body a 5px margin. in this case the div occupies its original width along with the 5px padding. in order to get rid from this problem.. you can reduce the width to 5px.

then your code will be..

```
div{width: 100px;}
div:hover{padding-left:5px; width:95px;}
```

do the same in your code.. you can find your own solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reduce the height of the `<a>` to 65px

**CSS**

```
#browse-posts a {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 20px 40px 0;
text-decoration: none;
color: #888;
height: 65px;
}

#browse-posts a:hover{
background: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I should of figured this out, but I think the since the padding wasn't pushing it past the height on the non hover I wasn't thinking about that.

Answer (score 0):

Padding, by default, pushes the boundaries of an element outwards. This is a result of something called the box model. The box model defines the way that the width and height of a element is calculated (basically, which properties will contribute or not contribute to this calculation).

In your case, the padding on the `<a>` element extends outwards past the edge of the container. It's not noticeable normally because the element has no background, but on hover you add one, allowing you to see the true size of the shape.

You can fix this in one of two ways (plus more that I'm not mentioning.. CSS is pretty versatile!):

First of all, you can change the box model to something that will take padding into consideration on the overall size of the element:

`box-sizing: border-box;`

You will need to use vendor prefixes for this property, like so:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

(note that this needs to be applied to `#browse-posts a`)

Alternatively, you can simply hide the issue using `overflow: hidden;` which will not fix the padding from extending outwards, but it will not be visible

This would go on `#browse-posts`

I hope that helps you. Also, just for future reference, when posting a question it is always a good idea to post some of your source code so that people can easily find the areas that need to be looked at, rather than just a site link.

Cheers!